# How to SSH tunnel through Heroku dyno?

Tags: heroku, ssh-tunnel, dyno

How do I create an SSH tunnel *to* a Heroku dyno?

Comment: Can you add some more details as to what you have tried?  A quick Google search revealed: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to create an SSH tunnel in order to proxy, you can create a SOCKS proxy as follows.  Assuming you have a local Heroku project, in that directory:

`heroku ps:socks` will create a SOCKS proxy on a `localhost` port.  You can then proxy through your dyno by e.g. `socks5://localhost:1080`.

Hope that helps!